# Seperate folder for images

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have an API that delivers images and puts them in a folder. I want to make that folder accessible via Django.

folder structure:

```
- theProject
   - static
   settings.py
   urls.py
   .
   .
   .
   - theApp
     - apiimagesfolder
     views.py
     forms.py
     urls.py 
     .
     .
     .
```

I tried adding the `apiimagesfolder` folder to my static dirs:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "theProject", "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "theApp", "apiimagesfolder"), 
]
```

and I tried accessing an image in `apiimagesfolder` on the debug server with `127.0.0.1:8000/imagename.bmp` but failed. What would the correct path be?
Is the path staying the same after deploying?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "apiimagesfolder"), 
]
```

Comment: yeah, me too :D

Comment: When doing this many other things on the page break. I think this needs to stay like is: `   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "theProject", "static")`. Did not get the other thing to work though :(